# Finding source of logcat message: surface (identity=xxxxx) is invalid, err=-19 (no such device)

Tags: android, logcat, glsurfaceview, orientation-changes

"surface (identity=xxxxx) is invalid, err=-19 (no such device)", where xxxxx is a numeric ID, of course.

This is a logcat ERROR entry which I get in 3 (three) instance at the same time, but the game I develop works fine. I'm just worried because this is an error, not a warning. I get the 3 identical entries when my game screen (GLSurface) is resumed due to Activity.onResume(). The screen behavior is absolutely fine in the practice.

Details: my game is subject to GLSurfaceView.onResume() as well as orientation change (i.e. it's set to landscape in the manifest and in configchanges, but obviously Android needs to change orientation to
landscape when I return from my home screen to the game). So I get the error shortly after the GL thread is resumed (during texture reloading).

I think I should worry, since it's an Error, after all. Stackoverflow requires concrete questions, so my question is: what is the reason and how it can be handled, or if it's unknown, where can I find it? Should it be in the Android open source, right?

Comment: I also got this error:(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188902/andenginethe-livewallpaper-app-cannot-open-setting-page