# AndEngine:The livewallpaper app cannot open setting page

Tags: java, android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I write a live wallpaper with **AndEngine**.

When I choose my wallpaper in the Wallpaper Selector it goes OK, except I click the "*Settings*" button(This action will crash the app).

Can anyone help me? THanks in advance!

PS:**[Error Log] 08-30 10:46:54.376: E/Surface(4246): surface (identity=1406) is invalid, err=-19 (No such device)**